# Probability axioms proof

Tags: probability

If $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)>0$ and $P(A)< P(\text{$A$ given $B$})$, show that $P(B)< P(\text{$B$ given $A$})$.

How would we prove this? I would like a formal proof but also an intuitive explanation. I don't understand how the probability of $B$ can be smaller than probability of $B$ given $A$.

Comment: Consider the extreme case where $A = B$, and $P(A) = P(B)<1$. Can you now see how $P(B)<P(B\mid A)$ makes sense?

Comment: Apply the def of [Conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) : $P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)$

Comment: @Arthur I see it now. In that case P(B given A) will just be 1. So, it will be greater than P(B)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so much! It makes perfect sense. But can we state that since P(A given B) is greater than P(A), it has to be the case that P(B given A) is greater than P(B) to make those two equal. Or is that a "not enough mathematical" explanation?

Comment: @user585380 Whether that's "mathematical enough" depends on context, most likely on your teacher or intended audience. As a logical thought, it's enough. But if you're unsure: $P(B) = P(A) P(B \mid A) / P(A \mid B)$ and since $P(A) < P(A \mid B)$, you can get somewhere by replacing $P(A)$ with that upper bound.

Comment: Okay. I'm preparing for an exam, so I want to be as precise and mathematical as possible.